# Automatic Translation Showing Incorrect Texts

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-translate

In my react app, some users are experiencing a weird translation error. We are using i18next to handle different languages. However, for some pages, I think Google might get confused and try to translate a word in Spanish thinking that it is a word in English with the same spelling to Spanish, which results in non-sense text being displayed to the user. I have no way of replicating this as it happens to random users but I was wondering if more people have the same problem or can offer guidance as to how to debug this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue, only workaround I have found is to disable all automatic translations adding the attribute `translate="no"` to the html tag (https://cloud.google.com/translate/troubleshooting).

This solves the immediate problem but disables all automatic translation for users that may still need them, not a good solution.